# Bottom sheet width is half of the screen flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, emulation

[image]

Flutter i am developing an app in 8 inch emulator. As you can see in the image my bottom sheet doesnt cover all the width. I tried to change constraints, containers width but nothing has changed.

i will add code in comment

Comment: showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            isDismissible: true,
            backgroundColor: black,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(12))),
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Center(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: double.infinity),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                  color: black,

Comment: Please provide the code you are using.

Comment: https://shrib.com/#Mayson4PgJqRK

Answer (score 1):

Did you try getting rid of the top Center?  You don't include the rest of the modal, so the combo of the Center, and perhaps some width constraint you have further down is limiting the width. Otherwise, include your full modal code in the question section, not the comments.

Comment: https://shrib.com/#Mayson4PgJqRK

Comment: Yeah, I think that top Center is causing the modal to shrink to the width of your text.  You don't need that Center anyway.

Comment: I changed it as you said but nothing has change. Do you have any other ideas

Comment: when i try show alert dialog its same. It response like the screen has half of width

Comment: on your container:  you have a maxWidth constraint, but not an actual width.  Set that with a fixed width beyond 1/2 your screen width and it will either widen the modal or show you where the conflict is.  I'd also clean up all your extra Centers and center alignments except the last Column, and just use a crossAxisAlignment there.  And dialogs will shrink to content, which you would want.

Comment: first of all thanks for your response but nothing has changed

Comment: Then perhaps your context from which you are calling the showModal is limited in width?  I took your code and ran it in dartpad here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=a03669fb064578b91b776b63e9821d27 and it opens full width, so perhaps the parent context is your problem.